# Save Apache Spark mllib model in python

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to **save a fitted model** to a file in Spark. I have a Spark cluster which trains a RandomForest model. I would like to save and reuse the fitted model on another machine. I read some posts on the web which recommends to do java serialization. I am doing the equivalent in python but it does not work. What is the trick?

```
model = RandomForest.trainRegressor(trainingData, categoricalFeaturesInfo={},
                                    numTrees=nb_tree,featureSubsetStrategy="auto",
                                    impurity='variance', maxDepth=depth)
output = open('model.ml', 'wb')
pickle.dump(model,output)
```

I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: can't pickle lock objects
```

I am using Apache Spark 1.2.0.

Comment: Hi, looks like a correct way to save\load models in Spark is using .save() and .load() methods for models (at least in Spark 1.3.0). But I got issues with this approach as well :( Described my problem here [What is the right way to save\load models in Spark\PySpark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29255145/what-is-the-right-way-to-save-load-models-in-spark-pyspark)

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the source code, you'll see that the `RandomForestModel` inherits from the `TreeEnsembleModel` which in turn inherits from `JavaSaveable` class that implements the `save()` method, so you can save your model like in the example below:

```
model.save([spark_context], [file_path])
```

So it will save the `model` into the `file_path` using the `spark_context`. You cannot use (at least until now) the Python nativle pickle to do that. If you really want to do that, you'll need to implement the methods `__getstate__` or `__setstate__` manually. See [this pickle documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickle-protocol) for more information.