# What is the right way to save\load models in Spark\PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I'm working with Spark 1.3.0 using PySpark and MLlib and I need to save and load my models. I use code like this (taken from the official [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-collaborative-filtering.html) )

```
from pyspark.mllib.recommendation import ALS, MatrixFactorizationModel, Rating

data = sc.textFile("data/mllib/als/test.data")
ratings = data.map(lambda l: l.split(',')).map(lambda l: Rating(int(l[0]), int(l[1]), float(l[2])))
rank = 10
numIterations = 20
model = ALS.train(ratings, rank, numIterations)
testdata = ratings.map(lambda p: (p[0], p[1]))
predictions = model.predictAll(testdata).map(lambda r: ((r[0], r[1]), r[2]))
predictions.collect() # shows me some predictions
model.save(sc, "model0")

# Trying to load saved model and work with it
model0 = MatrixFactorizationModel.load(sc, "model0")
predictions0 = model0.predictAll(testdata).map(lambda r: ((r[0], r[1]), r[2]))
```

After I try to use model0 I get a long traceback, which ends with this:

```
Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o70.predict. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method predict([class org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:333)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:342)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:252)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

So my question is - am I doing something wrong? As far as I debugged my models are stored (locally and on HDFS) and they contain many files with some data. I have a feeling that models are saved correctly but probably they aren't loaded correctly. I also googled around but found nothing related.

Looks like this save\load feature has been added recently in Spark 1.3.0 and because of this I have another question - what was the recommended way to save\load models before the release 1.3.0? I haven't found any nice ways to do this, at least for Python. I also tried Pickle, but faced with the same issues as described here [Save Apache Spark mllib model in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28427797/save-apache-spark-mllib-model-in-python)

Answer (score 7):

One way to save a model (in Scala; but probably is similar in Python):

```
// persist model to HDFS
sc.parallelize(Seq(model), 1).saveAsObjectFile("linReg.model")
```

Saved model can then be loaded as:

```
val linRegModel = sc.objectFile[LinearRegressionModel]("linReg.model").first()
```

See also related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32292254/how-to-save-models-from-spark-ml-pipeline/32664107)

For more details see ([ref](https://phdata.io/exploring-spark-mllib-part-4-exporting-the-model-for-use-outside-of-spark/))

Answer (score 5):

As of [this pull request](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/5243) merged on Mar 28, 2015 (a day after your question was last edited) this issue has been resolved.

You just need to clone/fetch the latest version from GitHub (`git clone git://github.com/apache/spark.git -b branch-1.3`) then build it (following the instructions in `spark/README.md`) with `$ mvn -DskipTests clean package`.

Note: I ran into trouble building Spark because Maven was being wonky. I resolved that issue by using `$ update-alternatives --config mvn` and selecting the 'path' that had Priority: 150, whatever that means. [Explanation here](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=740955).

Comment: Yes, I've seen this PR, thanks! But I haven't tried to build Spark myself yet. Also thanks for a tip for Maven :)

Answer (score 2):

I run into this also -- it looks like a bug.
I have reported to [spark jira](http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-6571).

Answer (score 2):

Use pipeline in ML to train the model, and then use MLWriter and MLReader to save models and read them back.

```
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml import PipelineModel

pipeTrain.write().overwrite().save(outpath)
model_in = PipelineModel.load(outpath)
```

Comment: thanks, but this question is very old :) many things have changed since the time it was asked.