# Save ML model for future usage

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I was applying some Machine Learning algorithms like Linear Regression, Logistic Regression, and Naive Bayes to some data, but I was trying to avoid using RDDs and start using DataFrames because the [RDDs are slower](https://ogirardot.wordpress.com/2015/05/29/rdds-are-the-new-bytecode-of-apache-spark/) than Dataframes under pyspark  (see pic 1).

[image]

The other reason why I am using DataFrames is because the ml library has a class very useful to tune models which is [CrossValidator](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html?highlight=crossvalidator#pyspark.ml.tuning.CrossValidator) this class returns a model after fitting it, obviously this method has to test several scenarios, and after that returns a [fitted model](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html?highlight=model#pyspark.ml.Model) (with the best combinations of parameters).

The cluster I use isn't so large and the data is pretty big and some fitting take hours so I want to save this models to reuse them later, but I haven't realized how, is there something I am ignoring?

Notes:

- The mllib's model classes have a save method (i.e. [NaiveBayes](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html?highlight=mllib#pyspark.mllib.classification.NaiveBayesModel.save)), but mllib does not have CrossValidator and use RDDs so I am avoiding it premeditatedly.
- The current version is spark 1.5.1.

Comment: +1 Good question. I am in the same place as I am just now making the switch from `RDDs` to `DataFrames`. I am in `1.6.1`, but I am having the same problem, because save functionality does not yet seem to be implemented for `OneVsRest` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36243455/spark-ml-save-onevsrestmodel

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### Spark 2.0.0+

At first glance all `Transformers` and `Estimators` implement [`MLWritable`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.util.MLReader) with the following interface:

```scala
def write: MLWriter
def save(path: String): Unit
```

and [`MLReadable`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.util.MLReadable) with the following interface

```scala
def read: MLReader[T]
def load(path: String): T
```

This means that you can use `save` method to write model to disk, for example

```scala
import org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel

val model: PipelineModel
model.save("/path/to/model")
```

and read it later:

```scala
val reloadedModel: PipelineModel = PipelineModel.load("/path/to/model")
```

Equivalent methods are also implemented in PySpark with [`MLWritable`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html?highlight=mlwritable#pyspark.ml.util.MLWritable) / [`JavaMLWritable`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html?highlight=mlwritable#pyspark.ml.util.JavaMLWritable) and [`MLReadable`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html?highlight=mlreadable#pyspark.ml.util.MLReadable) / [`JavaMLReadable`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html?highlight=mlreadable#pyspark.ml.util.JavaMLReadable) respectively:

```py
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline, PipelineModel

model = Pipeline(...).fit(df)
model.save("/path/to/model")

reloaded_model = PipelineModel.load("/path/to/model")
```

SparkR provides [`write.ml`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/write.ml) / [`read.ml`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/read.ml) functions, but as of today, these are not compatible with other supported languages - [SPARK-15572](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-15572).

Note that the loader class has to match the class of the stored [`PipelineStage`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineStage). For example if you saved `LogisticRegressionModel` you should use `LogisticRegressionModel.load` not `LogisticRegression.load`.

If you use Spark <= 1.6.0 and experience some issues with model saving I would suggest switching version.

Additionally to the Spark specific methods there is a growing number of libraries designed to save and load Spark ML models using Spark independent methods. See for example [How to serve a Spark MLlib model?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40533582).

## Spark >= 1.6

Since Spark 1.6 it's possible to save your models using the `save` method. Because almost every `model` implements the [MLWritable](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.util.MLWritable) interface. For example, [LinearRegressionModel](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegressionModel) has it, and therefore it's possible to save your model to the desired path using it.

## Spark < 1.6

I believe you're making incorrect assumptions here.

Some operations on a `DataFrames` can be optimized and it translates to improved performance compared to plain `RDDs`. `DataFrames` provide efficient caching and SQLish API is arguably easier to comprehend than RDD API.

ML Pipelines are extremely useful and tools like cross-validator or different evaluators are simply must-have in any machine pipeline and even if none of the above is particularly hard do implement on top of low level MLlib API it is much better to have ready to use, universal and relatively well tested solution.

So far so good, but there are a few problems:

- as far as I can tell simple operations on a `DataFrames` like `select` or `withColumn` display similar performance to its RDD equivalents like `map`,
- in some cases growing the number of columns in a typical pipeline can actually degrade performance compared to well tuned low level transformations. You can of course add drop-column-transformers on the way to correct for that,
- many ML algorithms, including `ml.classification.NaiveBayes` [are simply  wrappers](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/098be27ad53c485ee2fc7f5871c47f899020e87b/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/classification/NaiveBayes.scala#L98) around its `mllib` API,
- PySpark ML/MLlib algorithms delegate actual processing to its Scala counterparts,
- last but not least RDD is still out there, even if well hidden behind DataFrame API

I believe that at the end of the day what you get by using ML over MLLib is quite elegant, high level API. One thing you can do is to combine both to create a custom multi-step pipeline:

- use ML to load, clean and transform data,
- extract required data (see for example [extractLabeledPoints](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/098be27ad53c485ee2fc7f5871c47f899020e87b/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/Predictor.scala#L123) method) and pass to `MLLib` algorithm,
- add custom cross-validation / evaluation
- save `MLLib` model using a method of your choice (Spark model or [PMML](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-pmml-model-export.html))

It is not an optimal solution, but is the best one I can think of given a current API.

Answer (score 5):

It seems as if the API functionality to save a model is not implemented as of today (see [Spark issue tracker SPARK-6725](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-6725)).

An alternative was posted ([How to save models from ML Pipeline to S3 or HDFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32292254/how-to-save-models-from-spark-ml-pipeline)) which involves simply serializing the model, but is a Java approach. I expect that in PySpark you could do something similar, i.e. pickle the model to write to disk.

Comment: _I expect that in PySpark you could do something similar, i.e. pickle_ - maybe, but it wouldn't be easy.  Since PySpark ML is mostly a wrapper around Scala API, one would have to ensure that Scala model is properly serialized  / deserialized at the same time.

Comment: I could do it using scala, but I needed to do it on python :|

Comment: +1 is there an easy way (or any way) to persist a pyspark.ml model ? Not able to find any documentation on it