# How to save and load MLLib model in Apache Spark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I trained a classification model in Apache Spark (using `pyspark`). I stored the model in an object, `LogisticRegressionModel`. Now, I want to make predictions on new data. I would like to store the model, and read it back into a new program in order to make the predictions. Any idea how to store the model? I'm thinking of maybe pickle, but I'm a newbie to both python and Spark, so I'd like to hear what the community thinks.

Comment: This is slightly related to this question [Saving a ML Model for future usage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33027767/save-ml-model-for-future-usage), the difference is that in this question you ask to use the `MLLib`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can save your model by using the [save method](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html?highlight=logisticregression#pyspark.mllib.classification.LogisticRegressionModel.save) of `mllib` models.

```py
# let lrm be a LogisticRegression Model
lrm.save(sc, "lrm_model.model")
```

After storing it you can load it in another application.

```py
sameModel = LogisticRegressionModel.load(sc, "lrm_model.model")
```

As @zero323 stated before, there is another way to achieve this, and is by using the [Predictive Model Markup Language (PMML)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predictive_Model_Markup_Language).

> is an XML-based file format developed by the Data Mining Group to provide a way for applications to describe and exchange models produced by data mining and machine learning algorithms.