# Spark: Can I save models generated using ml package in spark 1.5.1?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml, apache-spark-1.5

I would like to save model created by spark's ml package as spark models(.paraquet) or pmml. The model.save method is applicable only to spark 1.6 or later versions. Is there some way I can save my models using spark 1.5.1?

Comment: You cannot because it is simply not supported in Spark 1.5. However if you get the parameters (e.g., weights, intercept, threshold, etc.) from the model and save them as JSON, you may be able to reuse the trained model later (with your own `predict`) function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save ML model for future usage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33027767/save-ml-model-for-future-usage)