# Is there a way to transform single vector with model trained by spark mllib

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

As far as I can see, `transform` method accepts only dataframe. Is there a way to somehow apply model to transform a single vector?

Answer (score 2):

There is not, or at least there is not if you ask about core Spark. Related feature request is tracked by [SPARK-10413](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10413) and [SPARK-10884](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10884) but none have seen much progress so far.

There exist external libraries which might address this problem, some mentioned in [How to serve a Spark MLlib model?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40533582/8972505).

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the vector to a single row data Frame. And then run the model on it