# Log (and then apply) Spark MLlib model from R to MLflow

Tags: apache-spark-mllib, sparklyr, mlflow

I'm using Spark MLlib functions (through the *sparklyr* package) to train a model but now seem unable to save the model in *MLflow* for future use.

```
iris_tbl <- sparklyr::copy_to(sc, iris, "iris_spark")
mdl_mllib <- iris_tbl %>% sparklyr::ml_linear_regression(formula = Sepal_Width ~ Sepal_Length)
mlflow::mlflow_log_model(mdl_mllib, "artifact_path_where_saved")
Error in UseMethod("mlflow_save_model") : 
  no applicable method for 'mlflow_save_model' applied to an object of class "c('ml_model_linear_regression', 'ml_model_regression', 'ml_model_prediction', 'ml_model')"

packageVersion("mlflow")
[1] ‘1.17.0’
```

What is a simple way to save this model in *mlflow* for later use **on a Spark DataFrame** such as:

`mlflow::mlflow_load_model(model_uri = "models:/mdl_mllib_project01/Staging")`

For context, I'm using Azure Databricks as the ecosystem.

#### Other places I've looked for answers

- These links don't seem to directly solve my problem (https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/models.html#id28; https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.spark.html#mlflow.spark.log_model), although maybe it's that I need to make a "pipeline" or that this works for Python but not yet for R?
- This question seems relevant but offers abstract answers rather than details ([How to serve a Spark MLlib model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40533582/how-to-serve-a-spark-mllib-model)).

Comment: Hello! I am trying to do the same thing and have the same problem. I'm using spark MLlib and am trying to save a model in MLflow. Were you able to find a solution to this? Thank you!

Comment: @ava Sorry, I ended up making an H2O model instead, which I can save and use later through `mlflow`. :(

Comment: No worries! Thanks for letting me know! Would you mind sharing the H20 documentation page that works with sparklyr?