# How to save Linear Regression Model in PySpark 1.4.2?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to save the model in PySpark 1.4.2. but getting below error

```
model.save(sc, modelpath)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'LinearRegressionModel' object has no attribute 'save'
```

Can you let me know where I am going wrong? Cannot figure out even in the [Apache Spark 1.4.1 example](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.1/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#module-pyspark.ml.regression...)

Below is my code,

```
>>> from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors
>>> df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
...     (1.0, Vectors.dense(1.0)),
...     (0.0, Vectors.sparse(1, [], []))], ["label", "features"])
>>> lr = LinearRegression(maxIter=5, regParam=0.0)
>>> model = lr.fit(df)
>>> model.transform(test0).head().prediction
-1.0
>>> model.weights
DenseVector([1.0])
>>> model.intercept
0.0
>>> model.save("path")
>>>model.save(sc, modelpath) --tried both got same error
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'LinearRegressionModel' object has no attribute 'save'
>>> modl = LinearRegression.load(path)
```

Last 2 lines are not working.

Comment: [Link1] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33027767/save-ml-model-for-future-usage#33038798)  [Link2] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33027767/save-ml-model-for-future-usage#33038798)

Comment: you cannot see your saved model also?  For loading, load through LinearRegressionModel and not LinearRegression.

Comment: @mayankagrawal when i am saving the model i am getting below error model.save(sc, modelpath)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'LinearRegressionModel' object has no attribute 'save'

Comment: @Prateek Please see above error

Comment: import vectors from pyspark.ml.linalg

Comment: **save** is not implemented in that version . Please check other questions I have linked

Comment: @Prateek thanks , yes save is not implemented in that version