# How to save the model after doing pipeline fit?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-ml

I wrote this code in Spark ML

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression
import org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline

val lr = new LogisticRegression()
val pipeline = new Pipeline()
                .setStages(Array(fooIndexer, fooHotEncoder, assembler, lr))
val model = pipeline.fit(training)
```

This code takes a long time to run. Is it possible that after running pipeline.fit I save the model on HDFS so that I don't have to run it again and again?

Edit: Also, how to load it back from HDFS when I have to apply `transform` on the model so that I can make predictions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Straight from the [official documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-pipeline.html#example-pipeline) - saving:

> ```
> // Now we can optionally save the fitted pipeline to disk
> model.write.overwrite().save("/tmp/spark-logistic-regression-model")
> ```

and loading:

> ```
> // And load it back in during production
> val sameModel = PipelineModel.load("/tmp/spark-logistic-regression-model")
> ```

Related:

- [Save ML model for future usage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33027767)