# Compilation error saving model written in Scala, Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, model, compiler-errors, save

I am running the example source code provided by Apache Spark to create an FPGrowth model. I want to save the model for future use, therefore I wrote the ending line of this code (model.save):

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.FPGrowth
import org.apache.spark.mllib.util._
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import java.io._
import scala.collection.mutable.Set


object App {


  def main(args: Array[String]) {


    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("prediction").setMaster("local[*]")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val data = sc.textFile("FPFeatureSeries.txt")

    val transactions: RDD[Array[String]] = data.map(s => s.trim.split(' '))       
    val fpg = new FPGrowth()
          .setMinSupport(0.1)
          .setNumPartitions(10)
    val model = fpg.run(transactions)

    val minConfidence = 0.8
    model.generateAssociationRules(minConfidence).collect().foreach { rule =>
        if(rule.confidence>minConfidence){  
          println(
            rule.antecedent.mkString("[", ",", "]")
              + " => " + rule.consequent .mkString("[", ",", "]")


                 + ", " + rule.confidence)
             }
            }
    model.save(sc, "FPGrowthModel");


    }
 }
```

The problem is that I get a compilation error: value save is not a member of org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.FPGrowth

I have tried including libraries and copying the exact examples from the documentation but I am still getting the same error.

I am using Spark 2.0.0 and Scala 2.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had the same issue. 
used this to save model

```
sc.parallelize(Seq(model), 1).saveAsObjectFile("path")
```

and to load model

```
val linRegModel = sc.objectFile[LinearRegressionModel]("path").first()
```

this might help.. 
[what-is-the-right-way-to-save-load-models-in-spark-pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32292254/how-to-save-models-from-ml-pipeline-to-s3-or-hdfs/32664107#32664107)

Comment: thanks for that. However for loading an FPGrowth model which would be the right type for the objectFile?