# IllegalArgumentException, Wrong FS when writing ML model to s3 from Spark (Scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, ibm-cloud, apache-spark-ml

I've created a model:

```
val model = pipeline.fit(commentLower)
```

and I'm attempting to write it to s3:

```
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem")
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId", "MYACCESSKEY")
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey", "MYSECRETKEY")
model.write.overwrite().save("s3n://sparkstore/model")
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
Name: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
Message: Wrong FS: s3n://sparkstore/model, expected: file:///
StackTrace: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.checkPath(FileSystem.java:645)
org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.pathToFile(RawLocalFileSystem.java:80)
org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:529)
org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:747)
org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:524)
org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:409)
org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1400)
org.apache.spark.ml.util.MLWriter.save(ReadWrite.scala:80)
```

I also tried with my access key inline:

```
model.write.overwrite().save("s3n://MYACCESSKEY:MYSECRETKEY@/sparkstore/model")
```

How do I write a model (or any file for that matter) to s3 from Spark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't exactly what I wanted to do, but I found a similar thread with a similar problem:

[How to save models from ML Pipeline to S3 or HDFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32292254/how-to-save-models-from-ml-pipeline-to-s3-or-hdfs)

This is what I ended up doing:

```
sc.parallelize(Seq(model), 1).saveAsObjectFile("swift://RossL.keystone/model")
val modelx = sc.objectFile[PipelineModel]("swift://RossL.keystone/model").first()
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't have S3 connection to test.
But Here is what i think, you should use:-

```
val hconf=sc.hadoopConfiguration
hconf.set("fs.s3.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem")
hconf.set("fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId", "MYACCESSKEY")
hconf.set("fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey", "MYSECRETKEY")
```

When i do `df.write.save("s3://sparkstore/model")`
I get `Name: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.S3Exception
Message: org.jets3t.service.S3ServiceException: S3 HEAD request failed for '/model' - ResponseCode=403, ResponseMessage=Forbidden
StackTrace: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.handleServiceException(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:229)
org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.retrieveMetadata(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:111)
s`

which makes me believe that it did recongnize s3 protocal for s3 fs.
But it failed authentication which is obvious.

Hopefully it fixes your issue.

Thanks,
Charles.

Comment: Thanks for the input!  I don't have a problem saving a dataframe, though.  The issue is specific to PipelineModels.  I'm adding an answer I found elsewhere.