# Saving Spark ML pipeline to a database

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-ml

Is it possible to save a Spark ML pipeline to a database (Cassandra for example)? From the documentation I can only see the save to path option:

```
myMLWritable.save(toPath);
```

Is there a way to somehow wrap or change the `myMLWritable.write()` MLWriter instance and redirect the output to the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible (or at least no supported) at this moment. `ML writer` is not `extendable` and depends on `Parquet` files and directory structure to represent `models`.

Technically speaking you can extract individual components and use internal private `API` to recreate `models` from scratch, but it is likely the only option.

Answer (score 0):

**Spark 2.0.0+**

At first glance all `Transformers` and `Estimators` implement `MLWritable`. If you use Spark <= 1.6.0 and experience some issues with model saving I would suggest switching version.

**Spark >= 1.6**

Since Spark 1.6 it's possible to save your models using the save method. Because almost every model implements the [MLWritable](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.util.MLWritable) interface. For example [LogisticRegressionModel](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegressionModel), has it, and therefore it's possible to save your model to the desired path using it.

**Spark < 1.6**

Some operations on a `DataFrames` can be optimized and it translates to improved performance compared to plain `RDDs`. `DataFrames`provide efficient caching and SQLish API is arguably easier to comprehend than RDD API.

ML Pipelines`are extremely useful and tools like cross-validator or different`evaluators are simply must-have in any machine pipeline and even if none of the above is particularly hard do implement on top of low level `MLlib API` it is much better to have ready to use, universal and relatively well tested solution.

I believe that at the end of the day what you get by using `ML` over `MLLib`is quite elegant, high level API. One thing you can do is to combine both to create a custom multi-step pipeline:

- use ML to load, clean and transform data,
- extract required data (see for example [[extractLabeledPoints](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/098be27ad53c485ee2fc7f5871c47f899020e87b/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/Predictor.scala#L123) ][4](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-pmml-model-export.html) method) and pass to MLLib algorithm,
- add custom cross-validation / evaluation
- save MLLib model using a method of your choice (Spark model or [PMML](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-pmml-model-export.html))

In `Jira` also there is temporary solution provided . [Temporary Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32292254/how-to-save-models-from-ml-pipeline-to-s3-or-hdfs)

Comment: No i dont think this would allow it. because in that also you need to save the model to a distributed file system. I dont think it will work with the Cassandra itself ! 

I have saved the similar problem. How we solved the problem was that , we saved the meta data in the Cassandra i.e URL and then saved the model in the HDFS itself ! I hope that it helps !